# Sonata Admin Bundle messed up

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm trying to install sonata admin bundle on last symfony version. But after I make few steps in docs(http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/getting_started.html) finished 2.1 and like they propose come to admin/dashboard. On this page I have messed up menu. Check image.
Maybe someone had the same problem? Thanks

[image]